# how to perform mathematical operations over a two-level class object heirarchy

Tags: python

I have set up a two-level class object hierarchy - I'm not sure if I am doing this in the most efficient way, or even if I am using the correct terminology (unlikely), but here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np

class mem:
    """this is a member with characteristics"""
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.val=i*i

class ens:
    """this is the ensemble"""
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.mem=[]
        for i in range(n):
            self.mem.append(mem(i))

num=10
e=ens(num)

print(e.mem[4].val)
```

gives the answer 16 as expected.

My question is how can I perform mathematical operations such as the max or mean across the ensemble member values?

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
np.mean(e.mem[:].val)
```

but this gives the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'
```

The only way I could get to work was to copy the values into a list and then perform the average, but this seems not very pythony... I am sure there is a neater solution.

```
l=[]
for i in range(num):
    l.append(e.mem[i].val)
np.mean(l)
```

this works and gives: 
    28.5

Comment: you use normal list to keep elements - you would have to keep them in numpy's array or pandas' dataframe to work without `for`-loop.

Comment: What's `pval`? Did you mean `val`?

Comment: yes, sorry "val", cut and paste error, corrected the typo, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more "pythony" way you can use iterators, that way you can avoid creating duplicate lists:

```
num=10
e=ens(num)

from statistics import mean

print(mean(i.val for i in e.mem))

print(max(i.val for i in e.mem))
```

Prints:

```
28.5
81
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add method or property in class `env` to get `val` from all elements in `mem`

```
class ens:

    @property
    def val(self):
        return [x.val for x in self.mem]
```

and then you can use `e.val`

```
print(np.mean(e.val))
```

---

```
import numpy as np

class mem:
    """this is a member with characteristics"""
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.val=i*i

class ens:
    """this is the ensemble"""
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.mem = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.mem.append(mem(i))

    @property
    def val(self):
        return [x.val for x in self.mem]

num = 10
e = ens(num)

print(e.mem[4].val)

print(np.mean(e.val))
```

Comment: very neat, thanks... I didn't know about the property functionality.

Comment: without `@property` you would use `()` in `e.val()` to get values. So it is not big difference.